# Which free VNC server works well with Windows 7 and how to advertise it via Bonjour for control by a Mac?

Tags: windows-7, mac, vnc, vncserver, bonjour

I need to control a Windows 7 PC via VNC from a Mac in an office LAN. Since the IPs are dynamically assigned, I'd like the PC to appear in my "Places" and in the automatically detected nearby servers in VNC client I'm using -- both of which require the PC to advertise its VNC server via Bonjour (right?).

I tried installing ultravnc, which works when I access it directly by IP, but it doesn't seem to advertise itself in the network.

Any ideas?

Comment: Samba? I think you mean Bonjour.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.neorouter.com

NeoRouter is a cross-platform zero-configuration VPN solution that securely connects Windows, Mac and Linux computers at any locations into a virtual LAN and provides a networking platform for various applications like remote desktop, shared folders and printers, offsite backup, voice & video chat, etc.

NeoRouter Free features bleeding-edge technologies and is released frequently. It is 100% free for both commercial and non-commercial usage.

NeoRouter Professional is designed for commercial usage in the production environments. It is mature and reliable. It also includes 1 year technical support. Try it free for 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would recommend LogMeIn Hamachi and RealVNC/LogMeIn Free.

Hamachi is a zero config VPN software that does not require any pinholes/port forwarding.

RealVNC has free editions for the server and viewer. (much better than Windows RDP imo).

LogMeIn Free is a combination of both Hamachi and RealVNC. You can install LogMeIn on each server/computer and access it via the web or create a shortcut on your desktop for each computer. They also have LogMeIn Ignition for Windows now as well as iPhone/Android/iPad that would allow you to access the computers remotely through a secure connection.

I've been using both solutions for years for personal use for free. They do have a commercial version as well.